# SP2013: Changing Width to Home Page Web Parts

Tags: 2013, web-part, javascript, css

The issue that I'm having is that I would like to change the width to the web part zone on my site home page. I want to change the width of the left web part zone so that it moves a few inches from the quick launch bar. Since I do not want to apply it to all pages, I have decided to add a script editor web part. However, the code that I am using is not working correctly. Do you see what I am doing incorrectly? Or, am I approaching this the correct way?

```
 <style type="text/css">  
.ms-wepart-zone
{  
table-left border: 2px;  
}  
</style>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move your content away from the quick launch, try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #contentBox {
        margin-left: 250px; /* default is 220px, so increase to whatever value you like */
    }
</style>
```